# Images not being deployed to Azure from GitHub

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, github

I have a website set up on Azure, and I've set up continuous deployment from GitHub.

I've made several deployments before and everything has gone fine. But this time I made several css changes and added some images, and for some reason the images aren't going through. My css changes did though, so I don't think there's a complete disconnect.

I checked the deployment log on GitHub, and the image additions are there. The deployment log on Azure shows everything is fine. I've also tried deleting the image, creating a deployment, adding the image again, and then deploying again. But the images still won't appear.

Any idea what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are your images set as content in the project?

Comment: Yes, it's a standard MVC project, they are in the /Content folder.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think the Build Action needs to be Content for them to get copied. In VS click on an image file and look at properties (press F4)